# Kotlin: how to pass a function as parameter to another?

Tags: kotlin

Given function foo :

```
fun foo(m: String, bar: (m: String) -> Unit) {
    bar(m)
}
```

We can do:

```
foo("a message", { println("this is a message: $it") } )
//or 
foo("a message")  { println("this is a message: $it") }
```

Now, lets say we have the following function:

```
fun buz(m: String) {
   println("another message: $m")
}
```

Is there a way I can pass "buz" as a parameter to "foo" ?
Something like:

```
foo("a message", buz)
```

Answer (score 510, accepted):

Use `::` to signify a function reference, and then:

```
fun foo(msg: String, bar: (input: String) -> Unit) {
    bar(msg)
}

// my function to pass into the other
fun buz(input: String) {
    println("another message: $input")
}

// someone passing buz into foo
fun something() {
    foo("hi", ::buz)
}
```

[Since Kotlin 1.1](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew11.html#bound-callable-references) you can now use functions that are class members ("*Bound Callable References*"), by prefixing the function reference operator with the instance:

```
foo("hi", OtherClass()::buz)

foo("hi", thatOtherThing::buz)

foo("hi", this::buz)
```

Comment: A member reference can be passed around but that would be a 2 parameter function in this case with the first parameter requiring an instance of the class.  A better way is to wrap the member function with a lambda that closed on the class.  Assuming all of the above was in a class:

`fun something() {  foo("hi", { buz(it) })  }`

Comment: is there anyway to do this if buz is generic and type inference fails?

Comment: It seem that functions that do belong to a class can be passed in if you are operating within the same class, as of kotlin 1.1 you can do it with `this::function`

Comment: In addition, if you would like to make the function parameter nullable, just wrap the type declaration in parentheses with a question mark at the end. e.g. `bar: ((m: String) -> Unit)?`

Comment: why are both parameters of foo named 'm'?

Comment: @MartyMiller they are not.  The parameter `m` is for foo, the other parameter is the parameter name of the function type passed in variable bar to the function.

Comment: @TylerPfaff There is a parameter passed within the call when it is the variable `bar` ... are you wanting to curry a parameter?  See this here: https://github.com/MarioAriasC/funKTionale/wiki/Currying  Or ask another question in Stack Overflow with your specific example, because I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Thank you!  I spent hours trying to find this information.  The kotlin websites aren't helpful when it comes to real examples.

Comment: Else you can add ```inline``` keyword to the function that will make your code work better

Comment: This is a bit confusing for me. So in the above code, who's passing the argument m: String for the function buz(m: String). It's used by something() function, but I don't see anyone passing arguments for buz?

Comment: @capt.swag the call in `something()` to `foo` passes in a reference to `buz` which is received as the parameter `bar`, so then the call to `bar` is actually calling `buz` for this one call stack and it is forwarding the `m` parameter to that reference to `buz`.

Comment: So because Java is a LISP 2, the JVM really wants to be, and so Kotlin is a LISP 2 as well  Ok, I can work with that. Just need to remember when switching to / fro JS, which is a LISP 1 :)

Answer (score 32):

About the member function as parameter:

1. Kotlin class doesn't support static member function, so the member function can't be invoked like:
   Operator::add(5, 4)
2. Therefore, the member function can't be used as same as the First-class function.
3. A useful approach is to wrap the function with a lambda. It isn't elegant but at least it is working.

code:

```
class Operator {
    fun add(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
    fun inc(a: Int) = a + 1
}

fun calc(a: Int, b: Int, opr: (Int, Int) -> Int) = opr(a, b)
fun calc(a: Int, opr: (Int) -> Int) = opr(a)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    calc(1, 2, { a, b -> Operator().add(a, b) })
    calc(1, { Operator().inc(it) })
}
```

Comment: In current Kotlin, you now *can* use a member function as a reference.  You should now update this answer.

Comment: By defining functions in the companion object calling code get a bit better and no new instance of Operator get created every time. This would look like a static fun in Java

Comment: Great solution, this is the only way I found that works when the function is in a class. I don't consider it ugly but beautiful, almost looks like an angular template variable but for code.

Answer (score 29):

**Just use  "::" before method name**

```
fun foo(function: () -> (Unit)) {
   function()
}

fun bar() {
    println("Hello World")
}
```

`foo(::bar)` **Output** : `Hello World`

Answer (score 8):

Kotlin 1.1

use `::` to reference method.

like

```
    foo(::buz) // calling buz here

    fun buz() {
        println("i am called")
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to pass **setter** and **getter** methods.

```
private fun setData(setValue: (Int) -> Unit, getValue: () -> (Int)) {
    val oldValue = getValue()
    val newValue = oldValue * 2
    setValue(newValue)
}
```

Usage:

```
private var width: Int = 1

setData({ width = it }, { width })
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is simple example where I pass the multiplication function as parameter to another function.

```
fun main(){
    result(10,3,::multiplication)// pass function as parameter wow kotlin amazing
}
fun multiplication(first:Int,second:Int):Int{
    return first*second
}
fun result(firstOne:Int,secondOne: Int,fn:(Int,Int)->Int){
    val result=fn(firstOne,secondOne)
    print(result)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Jason Minard's answer is a good one. This could also be achieved using a `lambda`.

```
fun foo(m: String, bar: (m: String) -> Unit) {
    bar(m)
}

val buz = { m: String ->
    println("another message: $m")
}
```

Which can be called with `foo("a message", buz)`.

You can also make this a bit more DRY by using a `typealias`.

```
typealias qux = (m: String) -> Unit

fun foo(m: String, bar: qux) {
    bar(m)
}

val buz: qux = { m ->
    println("another message: $m")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this inline using a lambda if that is the only place you are using that function

```
fun foo(m: String, bar: (m: String) -> Unit) {
    bar(m)
}

foo("a message") {
    m: String -> println("another message: $m")
}
//Outputs: another message: a message
```

Answer (score 0):

apparently this is not supported yet.

more info:

http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5485180#5485180

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-1183

Comment: This has been added to Kotlin, therefore this answer is incorrect now.

Answer (score 0):

Another example:

```
 fun foo(x:Int, Multiply: (Int) -> (Int)) {
    println(Multiply(x))
 }
 fun bar(x:Int):Int{
    return  x * x
 }
 foo(10, ::bar)
```

Answer (score -9):

First-class functions are currently not supported in Kotlin. There's been debate about whether this would be a good feature to add. I personally think they should.