# Reference to method of a particular instance in Kotlin

Tags: lambda, kotlin

In Java 8 we can have a reference to a method of a Class' instance. Here's an example

```
Function1<Integer, Object> ref = a::getItem;
```

a is an instance of the class `Adapter` that has the method `Object getItem(int i)`.

Can we do the same in Kotlin? I tried the same syntax without success. So far I was only able to create an extension method reference like so:

```
val ref: Adapter.(Int) -> Any = Adapter::getItem
```

But here I still need an instance of an `Adapter` to invoke it. The other alterantive I see is defining a lambda like this:

```
val ref: (Int) -> Any = { a.getItem(it) }
```

Comment: Capturing references are not supported yet, but will be supported in the future

Comment: possible duplicate of [Kotlin: how to pass a function as parameter to another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120697/kotlin-how-to-pass-a-function-as-parameter-to-another)

Comment: Your option using a lambda is the current best method as-of 1.0, although it will change in the future to be supported as @AndreyBreslav mentions

Comment: Watch this issue in YouTrack for updates:  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6947

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since Kotlin 1.1, you can use [bound callable references](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/bound-callable-references.md) to do that:

```
val f = a::getItem
```

```
list.forEach(myObject::myMethod)
```

Earlier Kotlin versions don't have this feature and require you to make a lambda every time except for [these simple cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496032/kotlin-function-reference/42496375#42496375).

Comment: Thanks for the proposal link. For a Companion object's function, only this syntax seems to work [with Kotlin 1.3]: `(ClassA)::function` or `ClassA.Companion::function`. The first one can only be used in Kotlin, so for consistency between Java and Kotlin code, better to use the second syntax if you need to reference it in Java as well.