# Member function cannot be used as argument

Tags: kotlin

With the following code:

```
fun someFun(x: Any) {

}

fun foo(bar: (val x: Any) -> Unit) {

}

fun baz() {
    foo(::someFun)
}

class Test {
    fun someFun(x: Any) {

    }

    fun foo(bar: (val x: Any) -> Unit) {

    }

    fun baz() {
        foo(::someFun)
    }
}
```

In the code *outside* of the class, everything works fine, no error. In at Test::baz where `foo` is called, I get the following error:

> Error:(53, 13) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is kotlin.reflect.KMemberFunction1 but (kotlin.Any) -> kotlin.Unit was expected

Why can't I use a member function as an argument like this? [The documentation](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references) doesn't say that I *can't* do this.

Comment: I've already reported this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6947

Comment: I've asked a similar question before here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022388/reference-to-method-of-a-particular-instance-in-kotlin It seems to be on the agenda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Documentation](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references)
>
> If we need to use a member of a class, or an extension function, it needs to be qualified, and the result will be of type “extension function”, e.g. String::toCharArray gives us an extension function for type String: String.() -> CharArray.

```
foo(Test::someFun)
```

The type changes to:

```
bar: Test.(Any) -> Unit
```

You can also just pass a lambda to the function to get around this:

```
foo { bar -> someFun(bar) }
```

Comment: Ah, I see. That bit of the documentation confused me a little. Error is gone after changing the parameter, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm curious... did you have to change it to `bar: Test.(Any) -> Unit`, or were you able to leave it as `(Any) -> Unit`? @Lander

Comment: I did in fact have to change it to `bar: Test.(Any)`. To me it doesn't make sense to have to specify the class name... I figured `::fun` would result in just some type of "function pointer" -- I don't see why my `foo` function in this case should have to care about where the function comes from. A way around that is to just provide a lambda like `{ bar -> someFun(bar) }` as an argument instead of `::someFun`.

Comment: Ah. I like the lambda idea. I added it to the answer. I agree... I think it's pretty crazy you have to change the type just to pass the class method in. That really codes you into a hole @Lander

Answer (score 0):

inside the Test class

change code

```
fun baz() {
    foo(::someFun)
}
```

to

```
fun baz() {
    foo(this::someFun)
}
```

would solve the problem!

**if you want to reference a type of function, let's say**

```
(Int,Int)->String
```

**and you have class A**

```
class A{
    fun whatever(a:Int,b:Int) = "${a},${b}"
}
```

you can reference the function using `A()::whatever`
where A() means an instance of A