# Kotlin: Method reference not working?

Tags: kotlin

It seems I'm unable to use a method reference of an object in Kotlin. This feature exists in Java.

For example in Java if I was looping through a string to append each character to a writer:

`string.forEach(writer::append);`

But in Kotlin using the same syntax does not work because:

[image]

Comment: They're separate languages. Why would you expect a feature in one to automatically work in another?

Comment: I thought that they added proper method references a few months ago. It's a necessary feature that saves boilerplate and that's what Kotlin is about.

Comment: They may have, I don't really know Kotlin. But I don't understand the connection to Java, since this question is fully about Kotlin. Have you checked the docs [on function references](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022388/reference-to-method-of-a-particular-instance-in-kotlin

Comment: It's perhaps not as you like it but the workaround to just wrap it in a literal function like { writer.append(it) } works ok.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starting from Kotlin 1.1 `writer::append` is a perfectly valid [bound callable reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#bound-function-and-property-references-since-11).

However, you still cannot write `string.forEach(writer::append)` because `Writer#append` method returns a `Writer` instance and `forEach` expects a function that returns `Unit`.

Answer (score 26):

For now, Kotlin only supports references to top-level and local functions and members of *classes*, not individual instances. See the docs [here](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references).

So, you can say `Writer::append` and get a function `Writer.(Char) -> Writer`, but taking a `writer` instance and saying `writer::append` to get a function `(Char) -> Writer` is not supported at the moment.

Comment: Thanks! Are there plans to add the feature in a future Kotlin version?

Answer (score 4):

I am using Kotlin 1.3 and while referencing a Java method I got a very similar error. As mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022388/reference-to-method-of-a-particular-instance-in-kotlin#comment56833323_28022388), making a lambda and passing it to the `forEach` method is a good option.

```
key.forEach { writter.append(it) }
```

Being `it` [the implicit name of a single parameter.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter)