# What is the equivalent of double colon (::) Java in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

```
orgList.getOrgMigrationMap().entrySet().stream()
    .filter(//some logic)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Trying to get the Kotlin equivalent of this code, but looks like double colon `::` in Kotlin means something else than Java. Can someone suggest?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-filtering.html#filter-by-predicate

Comment: They're called "method references" in Java, so went to the Kotlin docs linked above and typed "method references" into the search box there. The list included a topic called "[function references](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reflection.html#function-references)" which seems to suggest you use much the same syntax.

Comment: This nice post covers many already existing stdlib functions in Kotlin which are equivalent to Java stream intermediate/terminal operations. [what-java-8-stream-collect-equivalents-are-available-in-the-standard-kotlin-libr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34642254/what-java-8-stream-collect-equivalents-are-available-in-the-standard-kotlin-libr)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin: Method reference not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32598320/kotlin-method-reference-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

it's the same but it can also be used to get reflection information about the target [source](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/reflection#:%7E:text=In%20exactly%20the%20same%20way%20as%20with%20classes%2C,used%20to%20get%20reflection%20information%20about%20the%20target.).