# How to pass functions to function in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I want to pass one or more function(s) to a function but as long as it is a function literal or a package function it's working but when I change it to a function of a specific class (member function) I have the following problems

suppose I have these two functions

```
fun foo() { //doSomething }
fun bar(function: () -> Unit) { 
    //anotherThing! 
    function()
}
```

when I call

```
bar(foo())
```

or

```
bar(::foo)
```

I've encountered a type mismatch 
(Required: ()->Unit , Found: Unit)

**Note:** I don't want to solve it like this

```
bar( { foo() } )
```

or

```
bar {
foo()
}
```

Comment: This feature is not implemented yet, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022388/reference-to-method-of-a-particular-instance-in-kotlin

Comment: It works for me -- http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/f9jhaiqob1emh7ho02m7embdsd/979gqb7qh0saspc0ig6avidbq1

Comment: is it foo member fun?

Comment: yes it's a member function (I know which it's working for package functions)

Comment: Well, let's fix question.

Comment: You can use member funs w/o binding `this` like: `Foo::bar`

Comment: @bashor what do you mean? can you give a sample?

Comment: @siavash http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/f9jhaiqob1emh7ho02m7embdsd/6i7qn58hmgbt44m9pkr3j4e282

Comment: @bashor the example that you provide is near what I want but there is one problem, it is limit to a specific class and I cannot use that function over other classes http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/5iur76b0pfupug801sr8qfmctk/hl942gpljmgvsld2mtme9mv626

Comment: @siavash ok, You can write own bind fun: http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/f9jhaiqob1emh7ho02m7embdsd/r8g29o6busul6kurj7opiad2cl
But I don't sure that it simpler/better than just use lambda

Comment: @bashor The last example is not working! and in this case I don't want to use lambda because I want a function with 3 args for example, that 2 of it are functions, so how can I use lambda for it? (Note: that's my main goal) like this : http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/5iur76b0pfupug801sr8qfmctk/hl942gpljmgvsld2mtme9mv626

Comment: What doesn't work? I missed to call `f` in `boo`. Is it what did you mean?

Comment: Do you want something like this? http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/f9jhaiqob1emh7ho02m7embdsd/nr312ulsvbsasev6jc2oohnn2k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kotlin 1.1 and later you can use [bound callable references](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew11.html#bound-callable-references). e.g. `bar(::foo)`.

In the [second 1.0 Beta Candidate](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/11/kotlin-1-0-beta-2-is-out/) and other prior versions you could not pass around member functions. This issue was tracked as [KT-6947](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6947).

Answer (score 0):

I have just checked your example. It's works for me. Kotlin version 1.0.0-beta-2423

[image: Code in Idea]

Comment: I forgot to say which the function that I want to pass can be a member function otherwise you're right