# Kotlin function reference

Tags: functional-programming, kotlin

Let `records` be stream/collection and `extract` function which transforms data form an element of such collection.

Is there a way in Kotlin to write

```
records.map {extract(it)}
```

without explicitely applying`(it)` ?

E.g. `records.map(extract)` or `records.map {extract}`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- If `extract` is a value (local variable, property, parameter) of a functional type `(T) -> R` or `T.() -> R` for some `T` and `R`, then you can pass it directly to `map`:

  ```
  records.map(extract)
  ```

  <sup>Example:</sup>

  ```
  val upperCaseReverse: (String) -> String = { it.toUpperCase().reversed() }

  listOf("abc", "xyz").map(upperCaseReverse) // [CBA, ZYX]
  ```
- If `extract` is a top-level single argument function or a local single argument function, you can [make a function reference as `::extract`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references) and pass it to `map`:

  ```
  records.map(::extract)
  ```

  <sup>Example:</sup>

  ```
  fun rotate(s: String) = s.drop(1) + s.first()

  listOf("abc", "xyz").map(::rotate) // [bca, yzx]
  ```
- If it is a member or an extension function of a class `SomeClass` accepting no arguments or a property of `SomeClass`, you can use it as `SomeClass::extract`. In this case, `records` should contain items of `SomeType`, which will be used as a receiver for `extract`.

  ```
  records.map(SomeClass::extract)
  ```

  <sup>Example:</sup>

  ```
  fun Int.rem2() = this % 2

  listOf("abc", "defg").map(String::length).map(Int::rem2) // [1, 0]
  ```
- *Since Kotlin 1.1*, if `extract` is a member or an extension function of a class `SomeClass` accepting one argument, you can [make a bound callable reference](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/bound-callable-references.md) with some receiver `foo`:

  ```
  records.map(foo::extract)
  records.map(this::extract) // to call on `this` receiver
  ```

  <sup>Example:</sup>

  ```
  listOf("abc", "xyz").map("prefix"::plus) // [prefixabc, prefixxyz]
  ```

<sup>[(runnable demo with all the code samples above)](http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/e2dsmpb3vs4elaugjprp90tbqp/glu259po0vouhr93rf1pl41ktc)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

you could use method reference (similar to Java).

```
records.map {::extract}
```

take a look at the function references examples on kotlin docs
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references

Comment: This code doesn't do what it is intended to. Each item of `records` will be mapped to the function reference, and you will get a list of N identical items `::extract`.