# What different this::functionA between functionA() as params in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have two extension method

Function A is:

```
fun Activity.postDelay1s(run: () -> Unit) {
Handler().postDelayed({ run() }, 1000)
}
```

Function B is:

```
fun CustomRefreshLayout.setUp(containerRecycleView: RecyclerView, onResfresh: () -> Unit) {
with(this) {
    recyclerView = containerRecycleView
    setColorSchemeColors(Color.BLUE,
            Color.GREEN,
            Color.YELLOW,
            Color.RED)
    setDistanceToTriggerSync(300)
    setProgressBackgroundColorSchemeColor(Color.WHITE)
    setSize(SwipeRefreshLayout.LARGE)
    setOnRefreshListener { onResfresh() }
}

}
```

When I call function `a` I use this way `postDelay1s { initData() }`, but call `b` I need use this way `swipe.setUp(trade_list, this::initData)`.

I want to kown what different with `initData()` between `this::initData`in this two extension function

Answer (score 3):

You can call b with a [function reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references) as you already did (`::initData`) and also with a lambda like in a:

```
swipe.setUp(trade_list){
    initData()
}
```

It’s also possible to pass the lambda inside the parentheses which isn’t recommended in most cases:

```
swipe.setUp(trade_list, { initData() })
```

[Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html) says:

> In Kotlin, there is a convention that if the last parameter to a function is a function, and you're passing a lambda expression as the corresponding argument, you can specify it outside of parentheses

Also read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42496375/8073652).

Answer (score 2):

Your functions take the same type in their parameters (`() -> Unit`), so you can use call both of them in either way.

---

Let's see what the first syntax does:

```
postDelay1s { initData() }
```

Here you're creating a new lambda (anonymous function), whose body consists of only a single call to the `initData` function. You're basically introducing an additional level of redirection into your code.

With the second syntax:

```
postDelay1s(this::initData)
```

You're passing in a [reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references) to your `initData` method. This way, the `initData` method takes over the role that the lambda played in the previous version - the `postDelay1s` function will call this method directly, without the need for the additional step.

---

Both of these syntaxes can be used with your `setUp` method as well.