# Kotlin bound callable references inconsistency

Tags: reflection, kotlin

Today I was creating unit tests for my Presenter in Android app and I noticed some inconsistency with bound callable references. Is it under development or is it language bug? I found [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33805243/4643073) in kotlin 1.1 bound callable references are supported. But my code fails with kotlin 1.1.2-4.

In my presenter class, tested method reads data from database and `dao.getAllItems()` method have no parameters while view takes list --> `view.showData(List<Item>)`.

I'm using Mockito, RxJava2 and Room Persistance library.

```
class ItemsPresenter @Inject constructor(private val itemDao: ItemDao) : Presenter<ItemsView>
{
    val TAG = this.javaClass.name!!
    private val disposables: CompositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
    private lateinit var view: ItemsView

    override fun onCreate(view: ItemsView)
    {
        this.view = view
    }

    override fun onDestroy()
    {
        disposables.clear()
    }

    fun onGetItems()
    {
        Observable.fromCallable(itemDao::getAllItems)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                        { data -> view.showData(data) },
                        { throwable -> view.showLoadingDataError(throwable.localizedMessage) }
                )
    }
}
```

I have created test for `onGetItems()` method

```
@RunWith(KotlinTestRunner::class)
class ItemsPresenterTest
{
    private lateinit var view: ItemsView
    private lateinit var dao: ItemDao
    private lateinit var presenter: ItemsPresenter

    @Before
    fun setup()
    {
        RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.io() }
        dao = mock(ItemDao::class.java)
        view = mock(ItemsView::class.java)
        presenter = ItemsPresenter(dao)
    }

    @Test
    fun onGetItemsTest()
    {
        val list = ArrayList<Item>()
        When(dao.getAllItems()).thenReturn(list)
        presenter.onCreate(view)
        presenter.onGetItems()

        verify(dao).getAllItems()
        verify(view).showData(list)
    }
}
```

When I have setup as above, the test passes without problems. But when I change line
`{ data -> view.showData(data) }`

to

`{ view::showData }`

Then my test fails saying

```
Wanted but not invoked:
itemsView.showData([]);
```

Is it language bug? Because vulnerable code compiles fine and runs, it just causes the method to not be invoked at all, without any errors.

To clarify, the same code written in Java 8 works fine, lambda argument is correctly passed into method reference. As you can see in Kotlin bound callable references work fine when used with methods that takes no parameters, otherwise they are not called at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change

```
{ data -> view.showData(data) }
```

to

```
(view::showData)
```

to pass in the method reference correctly. This way, with `()`, you're passing in the method reference as the parameter of the `subscribe` method.

---

Using `{}`, you define a new function with a lambda to be given to the `subscribe` method.

Writing down

```
{ view::showData }
```

is equivalent to

```
{ it -> view::showData }
```

which is a function that ignores its parameter, and returns the method reference `view::showData`.

Comment: You are right, thats the answer. Somewhat misleading that you can pass method that takes parameters into lambda function and pass no parameters and actually compile that code.

Comment: 1.1.3 will contain an inspection to detect these cases: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17053

Comment: Oh, that's really neat.