# Overloading on reference to method of a particular instance in Kotlin

Tags: function, kotlin, reflection

It's clear on how to reference a method of a particular instance: [Reference to method of a particular instance in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022388/reference-to-method-of-a-particular-instance-in-kotlin)

e.g.

```
val f = a::getItem
```

However what if `getItem` is overloaded? I cannot seem to find any material on that.

Let's assume the `getItem` has the following overloaded functions:

```
getItem (String) -> Item
getItem (String, Metrics) -> Item
```

How do I select any particular function by bound instance callable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The context will determine which overload is chosen. In the case of

```
val f = a::getItem
```

The context does not say anything about what type `a::getItem` should be, so if `getItem` were overloaded, both overloads would be applicable, and there would be a compile-time error telling you exactly that. Something like:

> Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match.
>
> - `public fun getItem(name: String): Item` defined in ...
> - `public fun getItem(name: String, metrics: Metrics): Item` defined in ...

If you instead give it some information about the type of `f`:

```
val f: (String) -> Item = a::getItem
```

Then it will pick the correct overload.