# Kotlin: Passing operator as a function parameter

Tags: kotlin

I've the following function in Kotlin

```
fun evaluate(first:Int?, second:Int?) {
    var result = 0
    if (v.equals('*')) {
        result = (first ?: 0) * (second ?: 0)
    } else if (v.equals('+')) {
        result = (first ?: 0) + (second ?: 0)
    } else if (v.equals('-')) {
        result = (first ?: 0) - (second ?: 0)
    } else if (v.equals('/')) {
        result = (first ?: 0) / (second ?: 0)
    }
    return result   
}
```

I want to change it in a way so that I can pass as a third parameter needed operator and evalute the expression. Something like

```
fun evaluate(first:Int?, second:Int?, op: () -> Unit):Int {
    return (first ?: 0).op(second ?: 0)
}
```

How can I pass the operator as a function in this case? I checked the same kind of a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120697/kotlin-how-to-pass-a-function-as-parameter-to-another), but it is not clear how you can do that with operator.

Comment: Do you want to get rid of if-conditions? Where does the 'v' come from?

Comment: @ilya.dorofeev hhe shows the final intended function that gets rid of all the if conditions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Writing a [higher order function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#higher-order-functions) using a [function type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types) as a parameter allows using both built-in operators and [lambda expressions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expression-syntax) for the operation, so this would look like:

```kotlin
fun evaluate(first: Int?, second: Int?, op: (Int, Int) -> Int): Int {
    return op(first ?: 0, second ?: 0)
}
```

Which can be called with built-in operators such as:

```kotlin
val r1 = evaluate(value1, value2, Int::times) 
val r2 = evaluate(value1, value2, Int::plus)
val r3 = evaluate(value1, value2, Int::minus) 
val r4 = evaluate(value1, value2, Int::div)
```

And with custom functions:

```kotlin
val r5 = evaluate(value1, value2) { a, b -> (a * a) + b }
```

Now you can also assign the operators to variables, such as you `v`:

```kotlin
val v: (Int, Int)->Int = Int::times  // typing needed on left to avoid ambiguous alternatives
// and then later...
val r6 = evaluate(value1, value2, v)
```

Note that a function written for signature `Int.(Int)->Int` can be passed into a parameter expecting `(Int, Int)->Int` because the receiver `this` will be passed in as the first parameter.

Comment: This works as well: `evaluate2(value1, value2, Int::times)`, so you don't need a separate function, just the last one

Comment: Interesting that the signature doesn't match, but because of the receiver being the first parameter it still works.  cool.   Is that intentional or a bug?

Comment: confirmed it is intentional, wil update answer, thanks @voddan

Comment: It was a pre 1.0 feature)

Answer (score 1):

Change `() -> Unit` into `Int.(Int) -> Int`. Then all the other code should work as you've written it there.

On the calling side it `this` is the first int, and the first parameter is the second int: `{ other -> this * other }`

Answer (score 0):

you can try do that:

```
fun evaluate(first: Int?, second: Int? , v:String ): Int = v.op(first ?: 0, second ?: 0)

fun String.op(first:Int,second:Int):Int = when (this) {
    "*" -> first * second
    "+" -> first + second
//....
    else -> throw Exception()
}       
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(evaluate(2,3,"*"))
    println(evaluate(2,3,"+"))
}
```