# Kotlin: how to pass an object function as parameter to another?

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to learn functional Kotlin and have written this test code:

```
import java.util.*

data class BorrowerX(val name: String, val maxBooks: Int) {

    companion object {

        fun getName(br: BorrowerX): String = br.name

        fun findBorrowerX(n: String, brs: ArrayList<BorrowerX>): BorrowerX? {

            val coll: List<BorrowerX> = brs.filter { BorrowerX.getName(it) == n }

            if (coll.isEmpty()) {
                return null
            } else return coll.first()

        }

        fun findBorrowerX2(n: String, brs: ArrayList<BorrowerX>, f: (BorrowerX) -> String): BorrowerX? {

            val coll: List<BorrowerX> = brs.filter { f(it) == n }

            if (coll.isEmpty()) {
                return null
            } else return coll.first()

        }

    }

}
```

In the REPL I can successfully call "findBorrowerX":

```
import BorrowerX

val br1 = BorrowerX(name = "Borrower1", maxBooks = 1)
val br2 = BorrowerX(name = "Borrower2", maxBooks = 2)
val br3 = BorrowerX(name = "Borrower3", maxBooks = 3)

val brs1 = arrayListOf(br1, br2, br3)

BorrowerX.findBorrowerX("Borrower1", brs1)
BorrowerX(name=Borrower1, maxBooks=1)

BorrowerX.findBorrowerX("Borrower-Bad", brs1)
null
```

But how do I make the call to "findBorrowerX2":

```
BorrowerX.findBorrowerX2("Borrower1", brs1, BorrowerX.getName(???))
```

And pass the iterated BorrowerX to getName??

This looks related, but I'm not sure:

[Kotlin: how to pass a function as parameter to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120697/kotlin-how-to-pass-a-function-as-parameter-to-another)

Thank you in advance for your help with this!

EDIT:

Here is the equivalent Scala code for what I want to do:

```
def findBorrowerX2(n: String, brs: List[BorrowerX], f: BorrowerX => String): BorrowerX = {

  val coll: List[BorrowerX] = brs.filter(f(_) == n)

  if (coll.isEmpty) {
    null
  } else {
    coll.head
  }

}

scala> BorrowerX.findBorrowerX2("Borrower3", brs1, BorrowerX.getName(_))
res1: BorrowerX = BorrowerX(Borrower3,3)

scala> BorrowerX.findBorrowerX2("Borrower33", brs1, BorrowerX.getName(_))
res2: BorrowerX = null
```

Perhaps this is not possible in Kotlin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `::` operator to get a function reference:

```
BorrowerX.findBorrowerX2("Borrower1", brs1, BorrowerX.Companion::getName)
```

Here `BorrowerX.Companion::getName` is a reference to the function `getName` declared in the companion object (named `Companion`) of the class `BorrowerX`. It has the type `KFunction1<BorrowerX, String>` which is a subtype of the required functional parameter type `(BorrowerX) -> String`.

It's worth noting that you can use `::` operator to get a property reference too:

```
BorrowerX.findBorrowerX2("Borrower1", brs1, BorrowerX::name)
```

`BorrowerX::name` has the type `KProperty1<BorrowerX, String>` which also is a subtype of `(BorrowerX) -> String`. When invoked with the specified `BorrowerX` instance it returns the value of its `name` property.

Comment: Thanks Ilya, but I can't get `BorrowerX.findBorrowerX2("Borrower1", brs1, BorrowerX.Companion::getName)` to compile. I get 2 errors: "Error:(41, 57) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is KFunction2<BorrowerX.Companion, BorrowerX, String> but (BorrowerX) -> String was expected" and "Error:(41, 78) Kotlin: Callable references to object members are not supported". Any thought?

Comment: Oh, the former seems to be a reference bound to an instance of companion object, and bound references are supported starting from (not yet released) Kotlin 1.1. But you still can use `BorrowerX::name` in Kotlin 1.0.

Comment: You are correct: [link](http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/jen80pe3qlke33ile9qn6mvlov/nrhqkvhpdnkttmbcmkjha272ul) Fails with `v. 1.0.4`. Runs with `v. 1.1-M01`. Could you pass multiple parameters to getName if needed? Thank you.

Comment: Update: Appears multiple parameters are for "future use" in v. 1.1: "Error:(35, 56) Type mismatch: inferred type is KFunction2<BorrowerX, Int, String> but (BorrowerX) -> String was expected
Error:(35, 85) This syntax is reserved for future use; to call a reference, enclose it in parentheses: (foo::bar)(args)". See [val c](http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/jen80pe3qlke33ile9qn6mvlov/nrhqkvhpdnkttmbcmkjha272ul)

Comment: Hello Ilya. Is this still for "future use in v. 1.1..." in the current v. 1.1.2??
 Does not appear to be implemented yet? Thank you.

Comment: @ericky, there is no syntax in Kotlin like you're trying to use there. Use the lambda expression for partial application: `{ BorrowerX.getName2(it, 0) }`

Comment: This is odd. This syntax did exist and work correctly under v. 1.1-M01 on Try Kotlin (my comment on 10/4/16 with link). What happened to 1.1-M01?

Comment: @ericky I've checked the example with 1.1-M01 compiler and it yields the same error message about syntax.

Comment: Got it! Here is the syntax that works: `BorrowerX.findBorrowerX2("Borrower1", brs1, {BorrowerX.getName(it)})`. The working example can be found [here](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/jen80pe3qlke33ile9qn6mvlov/nrhqkvhpdnkttmbcmkjha272ul). Thank you Ilya.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [the documentation on lambdas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html):

```
BorrowerX.findBorrowerX2("Borrower-Bad", brs1, { it.name })
```

or when the lambda is the last parameter of the method:

```
BorrowerX.findBorrowerX2("Borrower-Bad", brs1) { it.name }
```

Stating types and parameter names explicitly often improves readability:

```
BorrowerX.findBorrowerX2("Borrower-Bad", brs1) { borrower:BorrowerX -> borrower.name }
```

Comment: Thanks miensol but I want to supply a named function - not a lambda - that takes a BorrowerX and returns a string. It works in Scala and I've updated the code to show how it's done there. Maybe not in Kotlin?