# Why I can use the name of the a lambda expression, but not the name of the function?

Tags: intellij-idea, lambda, functional-programming, kotlin

I can define a "big" function using a "small" function:

```
fun apply3(a:Int, b:Int, c:Int, func: (Int,Int,Int)->Int ): Int{
    return func(a,b,c)
}
```

I can call it so:

```
println(apply3(1,2,3,{a,b,c->a+b+c}))
```

On the other hand, if I want to use the same function several times and use a name for it, I have problems:

```
val plus1: (Int,Int,Int)->Int = {a,b,c->a+b+c}  //this is OK
...
fun plus2(a:Int, b:Int, c:Int)=a+b+c    // this too
...
println(apply3(1,2,3,plus1))    // this is allowed
...
println(apply3(1,2,3,plus2))    // this is NOT allowed
```

The last line is forbidden. With message:

```
Type mismatch
Required: (Int,Int,Int)->Int
Found: Int
```

Why? For me, plus2 and plus2 are the same things?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120697/kotlin-how-to-pass-a-function-as-parameter-to-another) has an answer that advises to use ::plus2 in my case. This helps technically but does not explain the difference between these two functions.

Comment: This error message is misleading and clearly broken

Comment: Reported https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-21966

Comment: @voddan Please, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47934397/can-i-use-a-name-of-the-lambda-as-the-parameter-passed-outside-of-parentheses/47934608?noredirect=1#comment82846149_47934608. I think, that is even worse problem.

Comment: @Gangnus I have. What's the problem? How can I help?

Comment: @voddan I have understood, Daniil, that you are an active person in the Kotlin community? A break in the substitution law should be covered at least by some explanation.

Comment: Syntax rules of many programming languages generally do NOT comply with the substitution law in one way or another. So IMO this case is no big deal and I am satisfied with how the docs explain this case.

Comment: @Gangnus  If you feel the documentation needs additional clarifications, please submit PR to https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-web-site. The team is usually very fast to review them and merge.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a [*function reference*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references):

```
println(apply3(1,2,3,::plus2))
```

Comment: Sorry, you yourself had made me to change the question so that your answer is not the answer anymore. But it was an answer for me and it did help. Merry Christmas and Happy New Year for you. Please, don't take offence, I am a  more theoretical person than you obviously.  :-)

Comment: @Gangnus - No problem :)