# Can I use a name of the lambda as the parameter passed "outside of parentheses"?

Tags: intellij-idea, lambda, functional-programming, kotlin

I can write a lambda expression outside of parenthesis, but I cannot put it there by name. I have tried many ways:

```
val plus3: (Int,Int,Int)->Int = {a,b,c->a+b+c}
println(apply3(1,2,3){a,b,c->a+b+c})  // OK
println(apply3(1,2,3){plus3}) // Type mismatch. Required: Int, Found: (Int,Int,Int)->Int
println(apply3(1,2,3){(plus3)}) // Type mismatch. Required: Int, Found: (Int,Int,Int)->Int
println(apply3(1,2,3)plus3)   // unresolved reference 
println(apply3(1,2,3){plus3()})   // value captured in a closure
println(apply3(1,2,3){(plus3)()})   // value captured in a closure
```

What is the syntax to put a name there (outside of parenthesis)?

I don't know why, but in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html) there is not a word on the theme. It says we could put lambda there, but not a word about a variable or constant that denotes that lambda.

Comment: That's because you can't.  And that's because there'd be no reason to :/

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth The substitution is the most base rule of logic. The theory of names is above logic. If it is broken, the case should be explained and covered by more specific rules. The dialogue "why? - because!" is not interesting even for kids games.

Comment: It's already been explained in answers that the docs say that you need to provide a lambda expression, so there's no ambiguity.  And I've also given you a reason - there'd be no compelling reason to allow this.  What else do you need?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I need to choose the language for one project. I considered Kotlin as a pretendent. But as I see, Java or Groovy functional programming are simply more consistent. Forbiddance without any objective reason will cause errors and misunderstandings.

Comment: @Gangnus If that is your concern, Java certainly is not different. E.g. "It is a compile-time error if a lambda expression occurs in a program in someplace other than an assignment context (§5.2), an invocation context (§5.3), or a casting context (§5.5)." in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27. A variable like `plus3` is valid in other contexts as well.

Comment: @Gangnus And the first paragraph of "Closures" in Groovy documentation (http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html) says: "While breaking the formal concept of a closure".

Comment: @Gangnus In fact, it wouldn't be a bad idea to try to read Java specification's "Names" and "Expressions" chapters: it's very careful about distinguishing values, expressions, names, etc. and Kotlin's notions of them are exactly the same (so far as I know).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't know why, but in the documentation there is not a word on the theme.

Yes, there is:

> > In Kotlin, there is a convention that if the last parameter to a function is a function, **and you're passing a lambda expression** as the corresponding argument, you can specify it outside of parentheses

`plus3` is an identifier and not a lambda expression, so you can't specify it outside of parentheses.

> The type of plus3 is (Int,Int,Int->Int). The same as of {a,b,c->a+b+c}. Look again at the messages that I am getting from Kotlin compiler.

You mean the error messages when you pass `{ plus3 }`? By Kotlin rules `{ plus3 }` is a lambda which ignores its argument (if any) and returns `plus3`. So the rule applies, and `apply3(1,2,3){plus3}` means the same as `apply3(1,2,3,{plus3})`.

> It sees plus3 as Int.

Exactly the opposite: it expects to see an `Int` as the return value of the lambda and sees `plus3` which is `(Int,Int,Int) -> Int`.

> So, the problem here is not of the high philosophical nature, but seems pure syntactic.

That was exactly my point: the rule is purely syntactic, it's applied before the compiler knows anything about type or value of `plus3`, and so it doesn't know or care whether this value happens to be a lambda.

The rule *could* instead say

> > In Kotlin, there is a convention that if the last parameter to a function has a function type, you can specify it outside of parentheses

in which case `apply3(1,2,3) plus3` would work. But it doesn't.

Comment: I have read that. Don't forget that ALWAYS I can use the name instead of the thing that is denoted by the name. It is the sense of NAMES. That part of logic (theory of names) is even much more fundamental than boolean logic. (the last is applicable to sets only) If a  set of rules does not fit the logic, it must explain this place outspokenly and in a very clear way. And I don't see a word about that.

Comment: `plus3` doesn't denote an expression, it denotes a variable.

Comment: No, plus3 is a constant. But even if it were a variable, it has the value and... I have explained already. The rule of substitution should work.

Comment: 1. No, it isn't, it's a local variable (if it's defined inside a method) or a property. 2. Yes, it has a value. This value is not a lambda expression, but the value of this expression.

Comment: You seem to be thinking about `plus3` as something like a macro which expands to a lambda. It simply isn't. Just like if you had `val plus3 = foo(0)`, `foo` won't be called each time `plus3` is used.

Comment: Alexey, I know that no real language can behave ideally. It is impossible due to Goedel. But the every place where it does not behaves ideally, should be explained. That explanation must be in docs, and it is not there. So, I am asking here. Sorry, you haven't explained it, too. You have said that I cannot do the mentioned substitution. I know it. But is a common rule is broken, it should be covered by a set of less common rules. What are they? Some forms are forbidden? I would like to know the list of them.

Comment: Again, your assumption that "But plus3 is {a,b,c->a+b+c}" (from the comment to another answer) is simply false. What's true is that the _value_ of `plus3` is the _value_ to which `{a,b,c->a+b+c}` evaluates. But the rule is "lambda _expression_ can be put outside of parentheses", it doesn't say anything about values.

Comment: I am afraid, your explanation does not work. The type of plus3 is (Int,Int,Int->Int). The same as of {a,b,c->a+b+c}. Look again at the messages that I am getting from Kotlin compiler. It sees plus3 as Int. So, the problem here is not of the high philosophical nature, but seems pure syntactic.

Comment: @Gangnus - `plus3` is the identifier of a reference to a lambda expression, it's not a lambda expression itself.  Not all possible lexical substitutions are legal; the language grammar defines which ones are actually allowed.  Here's another counterexample - this code is legal: `int c = (a + b); c++`, but here's some code that isn't: `(a + b)++`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth We are talking about functional programming. In it c++ simply has not sense. But passing (a+b) as a parameter will use the very (a+b) in the place of parameter use. Sorry, it seems you do not understand the functional programming and lambdas, let alone theory of names. Try Alonso Church, The introduction into the mathematical logic.

Comment: @Gangnus - None of that is relevant - we're not talking about functional programming, we're talking about Kotlin.  So what *is* relevant is Kotlin's [formal grammar](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#callSuffix), which defines what and isn't allowed in Kotlin (because you can't argue with the compiler, and the compiler is written against the grammar).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth So, you think that the authors of a formal grammar needn't keep up to the more common systems? Who would want to use such language? Really, I think rather they have some hole in explanations.

Comment: @Gangnus - I don't *think* anything, I'm just telling you what reality is (in this case, the reality is well-defined behaviour that serves a practical need).  A discussion about the problems with Kotlin's philosophy/design would be interesting, but it would be completely off-topic here.  Please try to ensure your SO questions remain objectively answerable :)

Comment: The answer seems correct, even if I don't like its consequences.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth The question is answerable. (yes/no) And the answer seems correct. But I still would like to have better explanations WHY?

Comment: @Gangnus - I can only speculate.  But possibly the Kotlin designers were concerned that code such as `apply(1, 2, 3) plus3` is needlessly ugly/confusing, with no practical benefits to outweigh those concerns.

Comment: @Gangnus See the edit for "Look again at the messages that I am getting from Kotlin compiler. It sees plus3 as Int. So, the problem here is not of the high philosophical nature, but seems pure syntactic."

Answer (score 2):

Placing a lambda expression outside of a function call's parentheses is the same as placing it inside the parentheses like this:

```
println(apply3(1, 2, 3, { a, b, c -> a + b + c }))
```

From here, we can simply assign the lambda to a `val` (as you have done) which results in:

```
val plus3: (Int, Int, Int) -> Int = { a, b, c -> a + b + c }
println(apply3(1, 2, 3, plus3))
```

Comment: Excellent. If it is the same, then put it outside, please.