# Kotlin send list of function to

Tags: kotlin

Using Kotlin how can a declare and call a function that takes a list of functions as a parameter. I've used parameters in functions that are a single function, but how do I do this for a list of functions?

This question shows how to send a single function to a function: [Kotlin: how to pass a function as parameter to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120697/kotlin-how-to-pass-a-function-as-parameter-to-another) What would be the best way to do this for a list of functions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can declare it using `vararg`. In this example, I declare a variable number of functions that take and return `String`.

```
fun takesMultipleFunctions(input: String, vararg fns: (String) -> String): String =
    fns.fold(input){ carry, fn -> fn(carry) }

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(
        takesMultipleFunctions(
            "this is a test", 
            { s -> s.toUpperCase() }, 
            { s -> s.replace(" ", "_") }
        )
    )
    // Prints: THIS_IS_A_TEST
}
```

Or the same thing, as a `List`:

```
fun takesMultipleFunctions(input: String, fns: List<(String) -> String>): String =
    fns.fold(input){ carry, fn -> fn(carry) }

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(
        takesMultipleFunctions(
            "this is a test", 
            listOf(
                { s -> s.toUpperCase() }, 
                { s -> s.replace(" ", "_") }
            )
        )
        // Prints: THIS_IS_A_TEST
    )
}
```