# Pass a static method as a parameter to another method in Kotlin

Tags: oop, kotlin

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120697/kotlin-how-to-pass-a-function-as-parameter-to-another?rq=1), a function can be passed as a parameter to another function as shown below

```
fun foo(m: String, bar: (m: String) -> Unit) {
    bar(m)
}

fun buz(m: String) {
    println("another message: $m")
}

fun something() {
    foo("hi", ::buz)
}
```

Similarly, we can also pass a method from a class

```
class OtherClass {
    fun buz(m: String) {
        println("another message: $m")
    }
}

foo("hi", OtherClass()::buz)
```

But what if the method we want to pass is static (within a companion object)?

```
class OtherClass {
    companion object {
        fun buz(m: String) {
            println("another message: $m")
        }
    }
}
```

I am aware that since it is static we can simply call the method directly without having to resort to passing it as a parameter, however, there are still some situations (such as when taking advantage of pre-existing code) where this would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access companion object of class use `${className}.Companion`. So...

`foo("hit", OtherClass.Companion::buz)`.