# is there any way I send a nullable Function<T,R> as parameter in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to use the public interface Function (as I learned it in Java) in Kotlin.

For this I created my method

```
fun foo(input: List<String>, modifier1: Function<List<String>>? = null){

}
```

as far I remember here I should be able to do `modifier1.apply(input)`

but seems like it is not possible (it is possible to do modifier1.apply{input} though)

Reading more about it I found this:

[Kotlin: how to pass a function as parameter to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120697/kotlin-how-to-pass-a-function-as-parameter-to-another)

So I changed my method signature to this:

```
fun foo(input:String,  modifier2: (List<String>) -> (List<String>){
}
```

Here I am able to do  `modifier2(input)`

and I can call foo this way

```
service.foo(input, ::myModifierFunction)
```

where

```
fun myModifierFunction(input:List<String>):List<String>{
   //do something
   return input
}
```

So far this seems possible but it is not acceptable to have the function reference as nullable, is there any way I can do that? or use Function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were using `kotlin.Function` instead of `java.util.function.Function` in your first example. Note that the latter takes 2 generic types: 1 for the incoming parameter and 1 for the resulting one.

The `apply` method you saw is the default Kotlin one: [`apply`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html), not the one of Java's `Function`-interface.

If you really want to have the Java-function as nullable type the following should work:

```
fun foo(input: List<String>, modifier1: java.util.function.Function<List<String>, List<String>>? = null) {
    modifier1?.apply(input) ?: TODO("what should be done if there wasn't passed any function?")
}
```

Kotlin variant for the same:

```
fun foo(input: List<String>, modifier1: ((List<String>) -> List<String>)? = null) {
     modifier1?.invoke(input) ?: TODO("what should be done if there wasn't passed any function?")
}
```

Maybe also a default function, such as `{ it }` instead of `null` might better suite your needs? (Java variant would be `Function.identity()`):

```
// java   modifier1 : Function<List<String>, List<String>> = Function.identity()
// kotlin modifier1 : (List<String>) -> List<String> = { it }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have a doubt...why a "it" is better than a null in that case?

Comment: It might not be better... it just omits the nullable function type and passes a valid default instead (~identity function). Probably a personal preference... if you use that non-nullable variant you can also `inline` the function which is generally recommended for functions having a functional parameter type.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the reference nullable simply with `?` — the only wrinkle is that the whole function type needs to be in parens first:

```
fun foo(input: String,  modifier2: ((List<String>) -> List<String>)? = null) {
}
```

As required, `modifier2` is optional; if specified, it may contain null, or it may contain a function taking and returning a list of strings.

As mentioned in another answer, `kotlin.Function` is not the same as `java.util.function.Function` — though in practice you shouldn't need to refer to either directly, as the `->` notation is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass in a function that takes `List<String>` as its parameter and returns nothing meaningful, the type for you is `Function1<List<String>, Unit>`. The method name for invoking a function is `invoke()`, which you could also do with just regular parentheses, if it wasn't nullable. All in all, your code could look something like this:

```
fun foo(input: List<String>, modifier1: Function1<List<String>, Unit>? = null) {
    modifier1?.invoke(input)
}
```

The `1` in the typename of `Function1` means that it's a one parameter function, there's also `Function0`, `Function2`, etc.

The [`Function`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-function.html) type on its own is not something you can use to call that function, as it's an empty marker interface. All functions implement this regardless of how many parameters they have.