# How to define function that I pass as a param as a nullable?

Tags: kotlin

According to this answer I can pass function as a param

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33402863/5709159

```
fun foo(m: String, bar: (m: String) -> Unit) {
    bar(m)
}

// my function to pass into the other
fun buz(m: String) {
    println("another message: $m")
}

// someone passing buz into foo
fun something() {
    foo("hi", ::buz)
}
```

So, there are actually two questions

1. If is it possible define `bar` function as nullable in order to have overload for this method.
2. How to pass function not from current class? for example `foo("test", myOtherObj.myTestMethod())`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how I did it:

```
fun foo(m: String, bar: ((m: String) -> Unit)?) {
    bar?.invoke(m)
}

// my function to pass into the other
fun buz(m: String) {
    println("top level fun: $m")
}

class MyClass() { 
    fun buz(m: String) {
        println("instance fun: $m")
    }
}

fun main() {
    foo("hi", ::buz)

    val myInstance = MyClass()
    foo("hi", myInstance::buz)
}
```

Comment: I think `MyClass()::buz` and for example `myOtherObj.myTestMethod()` not the same, right?

Comment: `MyClass()` is an instance like `myOtherObj`. `MyClass()::buz` is a function reference and `myOtherObj.myTestMethod()` is a function invocation.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko `myOtherObj::myTestMethod`

Comment: hmm, I got an error like `Required (() -> Utit)? found Unit`

Comment: Could you please check your syntax? I just ran the code and it is working fine with Kotlin 1.3.71