# How to call a method of a fragment from adapter class?

Tags: kotlin

I have seen many questions like this but they are not the same as my situation and I couldn't use those solutions.

I have a fragment (`OrdersByStatusFragment.kt`) and the method I want to call from the adapter is `getOrderStatusList()`

```
    class OrdersByStatusFragment : BaseFragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: OrderStatusLayoutBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_orders_by_status, container, false)

    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        getOrderStatusList()
    }

    fun getOrderStatusList() {
       
        showProgressDialog(resources.getString(R.string.please_wait))

        FirestoreClass().getOrderStatusList(this@OrdersByStatusFragment)
    }

    fun successOrderStatusList(orderStatusList: ArrayList<OrderStatus>) {

        hideProgressDialog()

        if (orderStatusList.size > 0) {

            rv_order_by_status.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            tv_no_orders_by_status_found.visibility = View.GONE

            rv_order_by_status.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
            rv_order_by_status.setHasFixedSize(true)

            val orderStatusListAdapter =
                OrderStatusListAdapter(requireActivity(), orderStatusList)

            rv_order_by_status.adapter = orderStatusListAdapter

        } else {

            rv_order_by_status.visibility = View.GONE
            tv_no_orders_by_status_found.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }

    fun successNewOrderStatus() {

        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    }
}
```

Adapter `OrderStatusListAdapter.kt`

```
open class OrderStatusListAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private var list: ArrayList<OrderStatus>,

    ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderStatusListAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
    class MyViewHolder(var binding: OrderStatusLayoutBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {

        return MyViewHolder(
            OrderStatusLayoutBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
}
   override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val model = list[position]

        if (true) {
            GlideLoader(context).loadProductPicture(
                model.image,
                holder.itemView.iv_order_status_item_image
            )

            val dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm"
           
            val formatter = SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.getDefault())

            val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
            calendar.timeInMillis = model.order_datetime

            val orderDateTime = formatter.format(calendar.time)
            holder.itemView.tv_order_status_order_date.text = orderDateTime

            holder.itemView.tv_order_status_item_name.text = model.items[0].title
            holder.itemView.tv_order_status_item_price.text = "$${model.total_amount}"

            holder.itemView.tv_order_status.text = model.order_status
            holder.itemView.tv_order_status_order_id.text = model.id

            holder.binding.spnOrderChangeStatus.onItemSelectedListener =
                object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                    override fun onItemSelected(
                        parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                        view: View?,
                        position: Int,
                        id: Long
                    ) {
                        holder.binding.tvSpinnerValue.text =
                            parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
                    }

                    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

                    }
                }

            holder.binding.btnOrderStatusChangeStatus.setOnClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                FirestoreClass().updateOrderStatus(
                    model.id,
                    holder.binding.tvSpinnerValue.text.toString()
                )
                Toast.makeText(context, "DB Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }

            holder.itemView.ib_order_status_delete_product.visibility = View.GONE

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(context, SoldProductDetailsActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_SOLD_PRODUCT_DETAILS, model)
                context.startActivity(intent)
            }

        }

    }
}
```

As you can see the `fun getOrderStatusList()` in the `OrdersByStatusFragment.kt` is actually calling a method in the `FirestoreClass.kt`. Following is the `getOrderStatusList()` in the `FirestoreClass.kt`

```
        fun getOrderStatusList(fragment: OrdersByStatusFragment) {
        mFireStore.collection(Constants.ORDERS)
            .whereIn("order_status", listOf("Pending", "In process"))
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                val list: ArrayList<OrderStatus> = ArrayList()

                for (i in document.documents) {

                    val orderStatus = i.toObject(OrderStatus::class.java)!!
                    orderStatus.id = i.id

                    list.add(orderStatus)
                }

                fragment.successOrderStatusList(list)
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                fragment.hideProgressDialog()
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved something like this is to pass a reference to the method into the adapter's constructor, then you can call the method in the adapter.
See [kotlin-how-to-pass-a-function-as-parameter-to-another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120697/kotlin-how-to-pass-a-function-as-parameter-to-another)

In general, the link shows a class containing a method called buz.
Let's say your adapter has a constructor like:

```
class MyAdapter (private val context: Context, val buzz: () -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>()
```

then you can create the adapter like

```
MyAdapter(applicationContext, ::buz)
```

In the adapter the method can be called normally:

```
buzz()
```

Comment: I went through the link, but as a beginner, I am not able to do this with my code. Could you tell me where and what I am supposed to change?

Comment: Sure, but to show you specifically with your code, I will need your code. Can you share a link to a repo?

Comment: I have added more code in the question, please check.

Comment: I added code in my original solution showing how to pass a method to an adapter. However. looking at your code, I think it can be simplified based on what it looks like you are trying to accomplish. Don't pass a function reference to the adapter, just pass the List to the adapter. Don't pass a fragment to  getOrderStatusList() (bad idea) - rather return the List. Then pass the list to the adapter.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your suggestion. I will try to improve the code. Regarding my issue, being a beginner I didn't understand how to do it. Can you edit my code?

Comment: Are you saying you don't know how to return a list from a method? Or modify the parameters of a constructor to take the list? These are different questions from the original and I would refer you to the kotlin tutorial for more explanations.
The code you are showing me would suggest you are not a beginner. Are you copying the code from somewhere? That will get you into all sorts of problems down the road.