# How to pass parameter in function as parameter to another and to create genric function in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, generics

I want to pass parameter in function but it giving error ***This syntax is reserved for future use; to call a reference, enclose it in parentheses: (foo::bar)(args)***. Also i want to make a **genric** **runFunction** which can take any parameter i.e. **Int, String etc.** In this example code i am sending **sumInt(2)** to **runFunction** also i want to send **concatenateString("John")**. Anyone Know how to achieve this. I tried search [Kotlin: how to pass a function as parameter to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120697/kotlin-how-to-pass-a-function-as-parameter-to-another)

[image: ][1]]

After updating the anwser and using lamba

```
fun main(vararg args: String) {
    runFunction { sumInt(2) }
    runFunction { concatenateString("John") }
}

fun <T: Any> runFunction(action: () -> (T)) {
    println(action())
}

private fun sumInt(a: Int): Int {
    return a + 2
}

private fun concatenateString(a: String): String {
    return "$a welcome"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the function call in a function if you want to pass parameters along to it. A lambda function is the most concise way.

```
fun main(vararg args: String) {
    runFunction { sumInt(2) }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @Tenfour04 i run your code it works it's not giving error but i am not getting sum instead i get some weird  answer **() -> kotlin.Unit**

Comment: Your `runFunction()` function prints the function object itself instead of the result of calling it. If you want to print what the function returns when it's invoked, then you have to invoke it. Change the content of that function to `print(action())`.

Comment: I update my code it print **kotlin.Unit** @Tenfour04

Comment: The function defined in your function signature must return Unit, so the result of `sumInt` is ignored and Unit is returned when the function is invoked. If you want it to return an Int, you need to change the signature. i.e. `fun runFunction(action: () -> Int) {`

Comment: Thanks i got it @Tenfour04